# MemberNotNullWhenAttribute ignored for async method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

I have code similar to the following.

```
public List<string>? Data { get; set; }

[MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Data))]
public bool Read()
{
    Data = ReadData();
    return Data != null;
}
```

The `MemberNotNullWhenAttribute` indicates that `Data` is non-null when the method returns true. This prevents warnings when `Data` is used without explicitly testing it for null.

This works great. But now I want to add an `async` version of this method.

```
[MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Data))]
public async Task<bool> ReadAsync()
{
    Data = await ReadDataAsync();
    return Data != null;
}
```

This compiles just fine and gives no warnings. But the `MemberNotNullWhenAttribute` is completely ignored. Using `Data` after this method returns true still gives the warning that it could be null.

Has anyone figured out how to indicate a member is not null in an asynchronous method? I'm writing a library and this kind of stuff is kind of important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async method is returning `Task<T>` which in this case will be `Task<bool>`. MemberNotNullWhen can't handle async stuff because awaiting Task is optional (neverminded that you will await in 95% cases).

Consider following code

```
async Task M()
{
   Task t = ReadAsync();
   string trim = Data.Capacity; // NullReferenceException. Field was still null because the task was not yet completed
   await t;
}
```

This involves a more complex code-flow for analyzing. There is open issue within [csharp-lang repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4994).